# How to add classes to a specific class in an ontology with sparql?

Tags: class, sparql, subclass, dbpedia, protege

We have a question about sparql, because we’re trying to link classes from dbpedia to our ontology in Protégé. Our protégé is about pets. We’re trying with the query below to get all the dog breeds from dbpedia and implement them as a subclass to our class ‘Dog’ in Protégé.

What happens with this query is that all the dog breeds become normal classes our ontology, but we want it to be subclasses of the class ‘Dog’.

Thanks a lot!

```
    PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
    PREFIX umbelrc: <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/>
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
    PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
    PREFIX ex: <http://data.kingcounty.cov/resource/yaai-7rfk/>
    PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>


    CONSTRUCT {
      ?x a owl:Class .
      ?x owl:equivalentClass [
        rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
        owl:onProperty ex:animal_type ;
        owl:hasValue ?xls ;
      ] .
    } WHERE {
      SELECT ?x ?xls WHERE {
      ?x a dbc:Dog_breeds .
      ?x rdfs:label ?xl .
      FILTER(lang(?xl) = 'en')
        BIND(str(?xl) as ?xls)
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you need them to be subclasses of something, wouldn't adding an **rdfs:subClassOf** triple be the way to go?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Right, that's the more obvious and formal way. But here the DBpedia category `dbc:Dog_breeds` is used, which should also be Ok - the only thing one has to take into account is that one has to use `dct:subject` as predciate and not `rdf:type`. In addition, this means that those are usually instances in DBpedia and not classes, but that's another point to think about then.

Answer (score 1):

Resources are connected to a DBpedia category by the property `dct:subject` and not `rdf:type` (aka `a` in Turtle). that means, change the triple pattern from

```
?x a dbc:Dog_breeds .
```

to

```
?x dct:subject dbc:Dog_breeds .
```

should work (modulo other issues that might arise afterwards indeed).